# Union with volatile and non-volatile standard layout types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, volatile, unions

It is legal to use active and non-active members of a union if they are standard layout types e.g. like primitive types as `int`.

On the other hand it is UB  to `const_cast`-away the `volatile` of a simple variable and use that variable.

Is it legal (no UB) to use both members of this union?

```
union VU {
    int nv;
    volatile int v;
};
```

More formal this should be

```
union VU {
    struct {
        int v;
    } nv;
    struct {
        volatile int v;
    } v;
};
```

Comment: Actually "If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence ([class.mem]), and if a non-static data member of an object of this standard-layout union type is active and is one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of the standard-layout struct members". `int` is not a struct, so no dice.

Comment: lawyery aside, why would you want to do this? Is the deeper quesiton if you can bypass `volatile` by placing it in a union? Disclaimer: Not trying to imply the quesiton would not be valid, it is. Its just curiosity.

Comment: Yes, excactly. `const`cast`-ing away is UB. The deeper question is about ISRs in µC, where you have several choices: declare the common variables `volatile` or make a `volatile`-access. In the ISR there is no need to make a `volatile` access and you typically want all optimizations to be performed.

Comment: [tag:union] is for SQL only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "use both members of this union" you mean attempting to exploit the common initial sequence rules to access a `volatile` object through a non-`volatile` glvalue:

```
union VU {
    struct {
        int v;
    } nv;
    struct {
        volatile int v;
    } v;
};
VU x;
x.v.v = 42;
std::cout << x.nv.v;
```

the answer is no, it's not legal. [[class.mem.general]/26](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#26) is actually very clear about this:

> In a standard-layout union with an active member of struct type `T1`, it is permitted to read a non-static data member `m` of another union member of struct type `T2` provided `m` is part of the common initial sequence of `T1` and `T2`; the behavior is as if the corresponding member of `T1` were nominated. [*Example 5*: ... ] [*Note 10*: Reading a volatile object through a glvalue of non-volatile type has undefined behavior ([dcl.type.cv]). — *end note*]

In the above example, the behaviour of reading `x.nv.v` is as if the corresponding member of the actually active member were nominated, *i.e.*, it reads the member `x.v.v` of the active member `x.v`. Since this is a read of the volatile object `x.v.v.` through a non-volatile glvalue, the behavior is undefined.

On the other hand if you were to do it the other way around (make `x.nv.v` active, then read it through `x.v.v`) then it would be legal; it wouldn't be any different from reading through `const_cast<volatile int&>(x.nv.v)`.

Comment: Is there any reason, other than overly simplistic standard writing, why the behavior should not be defined as though the `volatile` qualifier wasn't present in situations where every read of the storage would yield the last value written?  In other words, say that if there is a semantic requirement that an object's definition be qualified lvalue, that requirement applies to all lvalues used to access it, but if an object is declared `volatile` to accommodate situations where such a requirement might exist, code which accesses the object with a non-qualified lvalue would be usable...

Comment: ...only if such situations never arose?  Essentially recognizing three categories of objects: 1. Those that are not qualified volatile (and don't have to be); 2. Those that require `volatile` semantics and declared `volatile`; 3. those that don't need `volatile` semantics, but are qualfiied `volatiile` anyhow, and saying that any lvalue used for the second category must be qualified `volatile`, while those of the third may be accessed via both `volatile` and non-qualified lvalues?

Comment: @supercat What you're proposing is already the status quo. The semantics of volatile variables are implementation-defined; the implementation knows whether the variable's value can be changed outside the program. If the implementation chooses to make undefined behavior defined (by permitting access through non-volatile glvalues to variables that were "unnecessarily" declared volatile) then it absolutely can do that.

Comment: @supercat But the standard can't force implementations to do so "in good faith". Nothing stops an implementation from saying "well, as soon as you (the programmer) declare a variable `volatile`, any variable, I (the implementation) determine that its value can be changed outside the program".

Comment: @supercat So, in other words, if an implementation *wants* to do this, it already can, and if it doesn't want to, then you can't make them.

Comment: The Standard uses the same terminology to describe categories of actions which few if any implementations were expected to define in any subcases, and to describe actions which some implementations might define in all cases, but which at least some implementations might process unpredictably in at least some cases, but where the authors of the Standard didn't want to go into any more detail about which cases should be processed predictably.  The status quo is that some compiler writers regard all such cases as erroneous, and treat such characterization as an invitation to behave nonsensically.

Comment: It's too bad the authors of the Standard are so unwilling to recognize categories of implementations which promise to process things like `volatile` in various common ways, and to treat certain actions in ways that would logically follow from that, even if the behavior of those actions might not be defined on all platforms.  There is an absurdly large gulf between source-code constructs from which most implementations would be extremely likely to yield 100% reliable machine code, and those from which most implementations would be required to produce 100% reliable machine code.

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure I understand. If you are on an implementation that processes `volatile` "in various common ways" then that implementation might already be doing what you want (i.e. not treating non-volatile accesses as time travel UB etc). I don't see how the standard could force _only those_ implementations to do so while not imposing any requirements on the uncommon implementations that are unable to implement the semantics you want.

Comment: Consider the function `unsigned mul_mod_65536(unsigned short x, unsigned short y) { return (x*y) & 0xFFFF; }` Even on execution platforms that perform integer math with quiet wrap-around two's-complement integer semantics, gcc will sometimes process that function in a manner that may arbitrarily corrupt memory if `x` exceeds `INT_MAX/y`.  The authors of gcc treat fact that the Standard regards integer overflow as UB as having higher "priority" than the fact that the actual target platform would define the behavior.

Comment: @supercat Well, the problem there is that there are users who want it to be UB so that the compiler can optimize out comparisons like `x + 1 > x` (if `x` is an `int`, for example). The fact that you don't get the behaviour you want is because of the preferences of those stakeholders, not because the drafters of the standard are "unwilling to recognize categories of implementations".

Comment: It would be possible for the Standard to allow such optimizations without treating overflow as UB if the Standard were to recognize that e.g. overflow may yield a value that behaves like any mathematical integer congruent to the correct result mod the mathematical integer value (INT_MAX-INT_MIN+1).  If the drafters were willing to recognize distinct categories of implementation, then a program which starts with `#if __STDC_INT_OVERFLOW_BEHAVIOR & __STDC_BEHAVIOR_ANYTHING_CAN_HAPPEN` `#error Don't use silly optimization modes` `#endif` wouldn't have to worry about gcc-style nonsense.

Comment: As a more general principle, there are many actions which the Standard characterizes as UB, which could cause hard-to-predict side effects on some platforms, but which on other platforms could only have side effects if a compiler went out of its way to make them do so.  Applying the principle that such actions have no side effects on such platforms beyond yielding a possibly meaningless result wouldn't meaningfully impede genuinely useful optimizations, but would avoid the need for programs to handle corner cases which would otherwise be irrelevant.

Comment: @supercat Well, if you want a macro to detect whether integer overflow would be UB, and you're willing to simply not have your code compile on GCC, I see no reason why you couldn't propose this feature to the committee. The idea that the committee refuses to "recognize categories of implementations" is simply not true. Remember the concept of relaxed/strict pointer safety?

Comment: How about a standard means of determining whether a compiler is *configured* to process overflow in precise wrapping fashion, in a fashion that may not wrap precisely but would be free of outside side effects, or in a fashion that may arbitrary disrupt the behavior of surrounding code in ways not constrained by ordinary rules of causality.  Along with with ways of determining what other features and guarantees are supported by the corrent configuration.  If a program would have defined useful behaivor when processed on -O0, and there's no reason a compiler shouldn't be able to satisfy its...

Comment: ...requirements fairly easily without processing code in gratuitously inefficient fashion, compiler writers would have no excuse to regard the program as "broken".  A "link time optimization" mode which treated cross-module calls as memory clobbers, but still performed constant folding, would be able to usefully process many programs which are presently incompatible with LTO, much more efficiently than any modes that clang and gcc presently support.  I suspect the real reason clang and gcc don't support any such "it just works" modes is that people would start shunning more aggressive modes.

Comment: @supercat Again, if this is what you want, then feel free to propose it to WG21. I think your previous two comments have simply been restating what you already said before. I do not know whether your proposal will be accepted, but I believe I've made my point that, yes, the standard _can_ have features that let you check whether or not your implementation "is configured to" treat certain operations as UB.

Answer (score 0):

The C99 and later Standards deliberately waive jurisdiction over situations where it would otherwise unambiguously define behavior for some but not all implementations, based upon Implementation-Defined traits.

For example, under C89 the behavior of `-16384<<1` was defined unambiguously (and usefully) on two's-complement platforms where neither `int` nor `unsigned` had any padding bits or trap representations, but it would have yielded Undefined Behavior on an implementation where the bit pattern associated with `0x8000u` would be a trap representation if interpreted as `int`.  Because there may exist implementations where the action could invoke UB, the C99 reclassified such shifts on all implementations under the catch-all term "Undefined Behavior".

The semantics of `volatile`-qualified objects are Implementation Defined.  Most implementations define their semantics in such a way that applying a `volatile` qualifier to an object that wouldn't "need" one would yield semantics compatible with those where the qualifier was absent, in cases where the latter would be defined.  Because it is possible, however, that an implementation might store `volatile`-qualified objects in a manner completely different from non-qualified objects, and use a bit in a volatile-qualified pointer to indicate which kind of access would be required for the target, it would in turn be possible that using a non-qualified lvalue to access a volatile-qualified object might yield unpredictable effects whether or not behavior would have been defined in the qualifier's absence.

Consequently, the Standard waives jurisdiction over how implementations process code such as yours.  Such waiver is not meant to imply that implementations where the defined behavior of volatile qualifier would unambiguously specify the behavior of such constructs shouldn't behave in a manner consistent with that.  Nonetheless, because some compilers go out of their way to interpret such waivers of jurisdiction as an invitation to process such constructs nonsensically, such code should be recognized as being suitable for use only with implementations that refrain from such treatment.